# how to run polymer web app on localhost (xampp)

Tags: html, polymer

I'm trying to run polymer on a local machine with XAMPP but, it seems like it can't run it,
It shows nothing ,but when I inspect console on the page in browser , it's giving this error :

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///C:/Users/Home/Desktop/polymer/iron-component-page/iron-component-page.html

I'm using XAMMP on windows (Apache port : 80)

Comment: Did you use polymer-cli? Type polymer test and let us know what happend.

Answer (score 0):

Move your project into the XAMMP htdocs folder and you will able to use it from the `http://localhost/myproject` address. The `file://` protocol is not for the web.

If you `polyserve` it then the url should be: `http://localhost:8080/` or any port what you defined with `-p`.